# How to upload an image to Azure Blob Storage with v10 SDK?

Tags: angular, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to upload an image on the Blob Storage of Microsoft Azure using SDK V10 in Angular.

The following is the code I currently use to connect to the Storage and list all the containers names:

```
// connect to the Blob Service
const pipeline = StorageURL.newPipeline(new AnonymousCredential(), {
    retryOptions: { maxTries: 4 },
    telemetry: { value: "HighLevelSample V1.0.0" }
});

const serviceURL = new ServiceURL(
    `${this.blobUri}/${environment.azureContainers.sasToken}`,
    pipeline
);

// List containers
let marker;
do {
    const listContainersResponse: Models.ServiceListContainersSegmentResponse = await serviceURL.listContainersSegment(
      Aborter.none,
      marker
    );

    marker = listContainersResponse.nextMarker;
      for (const container of listContainersResponse.containerItems) {
        console.log(`Container: ${container.name}`);
      }
} while (marker);
```

Now I would like to upload a file (specifically, a image) in one of the listed containers (doesn't matter which one for the purpose of this question), but from what I have read in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-nodejs-v10), a filepath is required, but I don't have it. What I have instead is an object of type "File" in JS and, as far as I know, getting a filepath from the browser cannot be done due to security reasons!

Do you have any idea of how to achieve this?
How can I upload an image to the Blob Storage in Angular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example you referred to is for Node JS which has access to the file system. For uploading a file in the browser, you will need to make use of `uploadBrowserDataToBlockBlob` method.

From this [`samples link`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-js/blob/09f6a7ffe04cfdf5812d87ab0afc671f906fe504/blob/samples/highlevel.sample.js)

```
  // Parallel uploading a browser File/Blob/ArrayBuffer in browsers with uploadBrowserDataToBlockBlob

  const browserFile = document.getElementById("fileinput").files[0];
  await uploadBrowserDataToBlockBlob(Aborter.none, browserFile, blockBlobURL, {
    blockSize: 4 * 1024 * 1024, // 4MB block size
    parallelism: 20, // 20 concurrency
    progress: ev => console.log(ev)
  });
```